# Using Angularjs ngBind with javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In the following string, parsing the javascript object and placing it into an ngBinding is not evaluated it. I have a string that I am trying to include an specific part of a javascript object inside of, and am switching over to Angular for the relative ease of usage. The string at present is:

```
<html ng-app="bindHtmlExample">
...
<div>
    <p>"You owe ${{datatokens["DB.PMT"]}}"</p>
```

If I place something like     `"You owe ${{600+11}}"` inside of the ngBinding it properly evaluates to:

```
"You owe me $611"
```

Also, when I open the console it can accurately locate `datatokens["DB.PMT"]`. Thus, I must be conceptually missing how to make this javascript object available to this Angular application.

Comment: SHow your entire HTML instead of just a part of it.

Comment: if it's not in angular scope, angular can't evaluate it. If your data is in global namespace, pass it into a scope variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{{}}` binding operator in angular creates a binding from `$scope` to view. Any time `$scope` changes, the view will update based on this binding. It is the shortcut for the `ng-bind directive` and requires the `$scope` object to be present . You can use the binding operator in views for evaluating bindings and updating on change. For your case you can use the binding in view as below.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <div ng-controller='controller'>
        <div>You owe $ {{ datatokens}} </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('controller', function ($scope) {   
    $scope.datatokens = 600;
});
```

This will always update your binding and corresponding view element